# How can I get `vis.js` `vis-network` to run on React.js?

Tags: reactjs, charts, data-visualization, vis.js

I'm trying to use `vis.js` to render a Network Visualization using React. For that, I've been following the guide from James Tharpe: https://www.jamestharpe.com/react-visjs/. However, the follwing errors are raised...

[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF4YG.png)

Please check out my code on this repo:

https://github.com/murilobellatini/try-vis-network

Can you guys help me get this code working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've been facing the same issue. Add `options` in the `Network` constructor.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const network =
      container.current &&
      new Network(container.current, { nodes, edges }, options);
  }, [container, nodes, edges]);
```

full working stack: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e1pbxf?file=src/Graph.js

Try remove `options`. And it'll say *Cannot read the property 'solve' of undefined.*

Answer (score 0):

I used the react version of Vis js.

```
npm install --save react-visjs-timeline
```

and it is working properly

[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-visjs-timeline)